# Debugging Page Synchronization Issues in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm getting the following error,

> Uncaught exception: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize
>   with the page after 11 seconds. Please see
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

I've looked for any polling done by $http or $timeout. I would love any tips for identifying what is causing this. What is odd is that if I press keys or click around on the page the test will continue on to the next step.

Comment: Hi there! Can you give us some more details about your environment? 1. OS 2. Node Version 3. Protractor Version 4. Browsers you are running.  Also, it's quick and dirty but does bumping the `allScriptsTimeout` help?

Comment: You should be adding `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` line in your **conf.js** file inside **onPrepare()** function if you are not testing a non-angular app.